# How can I update php on my Mac?

Tags: macos, php

I have a MacBook Pro with macOS 10.7.5 and I want to update the integrated php from php5 to php8 or 7. How can I?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there only one problem, all the ssl certificates on macOS Lion a expired so curl don’t work

Comment: That’s a separate problem.  You really need to upgrade the OS on your Mac.

Comment: Thanks but I realized that the script site fortunately for me is http is not https